# Covering a 30-in x 7ft space that's suited for a door?

Tags: doors

We have a bedroom with 30-inch x 7-ft opening that takes me to a bathroom and a closet. This opening is ideal for a door, but it's solid concrete and very difficult to drill.

So I was thinking of putting something that would cover this hole, but is easy to install. I was thinking of an accordion door or something very simple, but I don't know if these exist for this type of application. I prefer not having to drill a frame into the concrete.

This connects to a bathroom, so there's no need for something as sophisticated as a door. The only reason I wanted to cover it is because the bedroom has an A/C so the air escapes to the bathroom and closet, and it becomes very inefficient.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could mount curtain hardware on the ceiling and use a curtain to close off the opening.

Answer (score 1):

Almost any type of door is going to need to be securely mounted, and therefore don't solve your initial problem. I'd argue that mounting a door wouldn't be that difficult, but....

A weighted curtain on an expansion pole might do. Most aren't 7 feet high, but you could probably find or make something fairly easily.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an expandable shower curtain rod to hold a cloth or leather shower curtain or home-made curtain w/loops.  It's very cheap, has virtually no installation, lets you pick a wide variety of fabrics from fine to cheap, and doesn't look out of place. Worked great for me in an old APT I couldn't mod...